# How can I save tablerate_bestway shipping method in Magento order saving?

Tags: magento

While saving order programmatically, I am passing table (tablerate_bestway), but it is giving error

```
'Please specify a shipping method.'
```

My code to save shipping method

```
$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                    ->setShouldIgnoreValidation(true)
                    ->setShippingMethod("tablerate_bestway")
                    ->collectShippingRates();
```

However, if I pass flatrate_flatrate, it works. How to save tablerate_bestway?

Both, flat_rate and tablerate_bestway enable in Admin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution sample is:

```
$shippingAddress->removeAllShippingRates()
            ->setCollectShippingRates(true)
            ->setShippingMethod('tablerate_bestway')
            ->setShippingDescription('Table Rate - Best Way');
```

Add Shipping Description and do not collect shipping charge.